# gcc usb.h not found

Tags: usb, compiling, gcc, make

I'm trying to compile a little program with GCC, but the command `make ./temper` gives me this error:

`gcc -Wall temper.c pcsensor.c -o temper -lusb In file included from temper.c:8: pcsensor.h:25:10: fatal error: usb.h: Fila eller mappa finnes ikke 25 | #include <usb.h> |          ^~~~~~~ compilation terminated. In file included from pcsensor.c:25: pcsensor.h:25:10: fatal error: usb.h: Fila eller mappa finnes ikke 25 | #include <usb.h> |          ^~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

I have installed

- libusb-compat-devel
- libusb-0.1.4-dev
- libusb-0.1-4
- libusb-1.0.0-dev
- libusb-1.0-0
- build-essential

My questions are:
Where can I find this usb.h file? I've been googling for several hours with no luck.
Am I missing something?
Should I remove any of the mentioned packages?
What is the path to usb.h when it's installed on the system?

Comment: How about `libusb-dev`?

Comment: Thanks, Ray! That was it. I installed it and it now compiles normally. Problem solved.

Comment: Please use the checkmark on Ray's answer to mark it as "Accepted" and mark the issue as solved.

Comment: How do I mark as solved?

Comment: @Bambino You did it correctly; thanks!  And I hope it helps you with future similar problems!

Comment: FYI I found an updated fork of the `pcsensor` software at https://github.com/shakemid/pcsensor-temper which compiled in Nov 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, I have the program `apt-file` installed.  After you install it, do a `apt-file update`.  And then, I ran this command:

`sudo apt-file search usb.h | grep \/usb.h$ | less`

which searches for the file `usb.h` in all packages.  From the long list, I restricted it to files that end in (i.e., the purpose of the `$`) `/usb.h`.  From that list, I guessed that `libusb-dev` was the file you were missing.

All the others did not look close to what you had been installing.